# LDAP User/Group filter HIVE

Tags: hive, ldap, openldap

I have a Ldap server and a group.
Now I want to do the Ldap authentication for AWS HIVE using that group.
Please find the details below:

```
**CN=hadoop-admins
  OU=Groups,OU=Root
  DC=int,DC=domain,DC=com**
```

I have put the values in the following hive properties:

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupDNPattern></name>  
<value>uid=%s,OU=Groups,OU=Root,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=com:CN=%s,
CN=Groups,ou=Root,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=com</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupFilter</name>
<value>hadoop-admins</value>
</property>
```

But the authentication failed with the below error:

```
**2017-12-28T12:45:27,064 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-33([])]: ldap.LdapSearch (LdapSearch.java:findUserDn(100)) - Expected exactly one user result for the user: Aditya.Tiwari, but got 0. Returning null**
```

I am part of the ldap group, than also it is failing. Can someone please help me out with this?